# How to use foreign key field in a serializer in Django?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models User and Company:-

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )

    objects = UserManager()
```

and

```
class CompanyModel(basemodel.BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='owner')
    ...
```

Now while creating the user only, I want to ask the Company name and create the company at that time only

Here is my serializer:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    company = serializers.RelatedField(queryset=CompanyModel.objects.all())
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, )

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if FederatedIdentityModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise APIException(
                detail="Email id already exists!",
                code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
            )
        return email.lower()

    def validate_company(self, company):
        if CompanyModel.objects.filter(name__iexact=company).exists():
            raise APIException(
                detail="Company already exists!",
                code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
            )
        return company.lower()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

                user_profile = UserProfileModel.objects.create(user=user)
                user_profile.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
                user_profile.save()

                company_profile = CompanyModel.objects.create(user=user, name=self.company)
                company_profile.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
                company_profile.save()

                return user
        except APIException:
            raise APIException(
                detail="Failed to register",
                code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'username', 'email', 'company']
```

But on the server the company field is appearing as a dropdown field.
How can I write my company field to create user as well as company at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add @property to model and link serializer not to model field but to this property.

PS avoid name duplicates for the model and properties.

PPS you can add source param to serializer.

PPPs you can make a separate serializer for company and link it in another serializer like:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

taken from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: I tried to create a seperate serilaizer for company and add it as a field to user serializer but I can't make read_only=True as I have to add company name at that time only
Without read_only I get the error for queryset.

Comment: Are you sure in your model ? why company has a user as a foreign key and not vice versa.
It has to be smth. like:

    class User(AbstractUser):

         id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
         company = models.ForeignKey(User, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
         objects = UserManager()

and nothing with user in the company model

than in serializer simply second line:
company = serializers.Charfield(source='company.name')

Comment: user is supposed to be the owner of the company, so I added a fk in the company model

Comment: does other users suggested to be in the company  ?

Comment: You will create a company instance for each user in those case

Comment: if you need to mark user as the owner and he has to be unique simply add boolean field is_owner, and add 'unique_together" in Meta for company and is_owner - in the User Model

Comment: okay, I get it,I will try to modify models accoridngly.Thanks!

Comment: You will create a company instance for each user in your case. please suggest to change  model